# Rails: Why can't I run .paginate on current_user.friends?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, pagination, associations

I'm using the Amistad gem to create a friend system. It includes a friendship model and controller, which I assume are associated with my user model in various :through ways etc., and all the functions seem to work so far.

Looping through current_user.friends in a view gives *a user's friends*, and lets you access all the normal user fields. e.g. .email, .name etc. on each.

Now i'd like to paginate and apply search_for to current_user.friends, like I normally do on my user model stuff, but it doesn't work.

So this, works:

```
User.order('created_at desc').search_for(params[:search]).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
```

But this

```
current_user.friends.search_for(params[:search]).paginate(per_page: 10, page: params[:page])
```

gives

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `search_for' for #<Array:0x007faac0b0db10>):
```

or this, when I knock out search_for

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `paginate' for #<Array:0x007faac015c7d8>):
```

Hoping there is a simple answer here!

**EDIT** Maybe I could work around this by doing User.where(current_user.friends) or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User.order... returns an ActiveRelation object, current_user.friends returns an Array.
Try this.

```
User.joins('INNER JOIN friendships ON friendships.friend_id = users.id').where(:friendships => {:user_id => current_user.id, :pending => false, :blocker_id => nil})
```

Comment: thank you. Do you know if its possible to get the ActiveRelation object for current_user.friends?

Comment: I think you have to go through Friendships, something like this: User.joins(:friendships).where(:friendships => {:friendable_id => current_user.id}) maybe it's a :friend_id instead of :friendable_id

Comment: seems to so nearly work - no error any more, I just get no items, with User.joins(:friendships).where(:friendships => {:friend_id => current_user.id})

Comment: Check your database, see what data is in there, for which user, maybe this user doesn't have friendship records? Also try running the query AR generates to see if you can manually run it in something like Sequel Pro against the database.

Comment: Definitely has 4 friends with current_user.friends. I just looked at the SQL query - its "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "users" INNER JOIN "friendships" ON "friendships"."user_id" = "users"."id" WHERE "friendships"."friend_id" = 1"  -  interesting - my user has ID 1 - i'm not looking for where friend_id = 1?

Comment: when I change friend_id to user_id, I get 4 copies of my own user - progress! any idea how I can re-work this to get the friend users instead?

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much! Had to make a small correction ':pending => false'